# Microtek ScanMaker 3880 drivers for 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, drivers, scanner

Is there available Microtek ScanMaker 3880 drivers for Ubuntu 10.04? I couldn't found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SANE-Project website](http://www.sane-project.org/unsupported/microtek-scanmaker-3880.html) says it is not a supported product.
The SANE project is an OpenSource project providing support for Scanners where the manufacturers have not.

Good vendors such as Epson and HP provide scanner support.  You'll notice Microtek on their website provide support for Windows and to a lesser extent Apple Macs.

Double check that your scanner is actually the USB device that they say is not supported - details of how to do this are via the linked web-page.

The only alternative I can think of is to use VirtualBox + Windows + VirtualBox Guest Additions to connect the USB device to the virtual guest.

Comment: yeah it's connected by USB